# I need to send an attachment with email using Google Script Editor but I can't get the file to attach

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am having a lot of trouble with actually getting the file to attach to the email I'm sending, I have been using the code below and the email is sending but the file is not being included.

```
function myCoding() {
  var array = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();      
  for(var i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    var loopEmail = array[i][0];
    var loopName = array[i][1];
    var loopNN = array[i][2];
    var loopSize = array[i][3];
    var loopColour = array[i][4];      
    text = "Hey " + loopName;
    text1 = "\n Your full name for the hoodie is: "+ loopName + ", your nickname for your hoodie is " + loopNN + " and your size is " +loopSize + ". You have chosen the colour "+loopColour + ".";
    text3 = "\n"
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('DrinksShopPartnerProgram.pdf');
    if (file.hasNext()) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(loopEmail, "DGS", text + text3 + text1 + text3, file);
    attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF, )]

    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have several files with that name? if not, use only the Id so you won't need the File iterator. Also, `attachments` is after the `;`, so it's outside the GmailApp method.

Comment: No its just the one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options):

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
GmailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
});
```

So you can modify your code to:

```
function myCoding() {
  var array = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();      
  for(var i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    var loopEmail = array[i][0];
    var loopName = array[i][1];
    var loopNN = array[i][2];
    var loopSize = array[i][3];
    var loopColour = array[i][4];      
    text = "Hey " + loopName;
    text1 = "\n Your full name for the hoodie is: "+ loopName + ", your nickname for your hoodie is " + loopNN + " and your size is " +loopSize + ". You have chosen the colour "+loopColour + ".";
    text3 = "\n"
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID of DrinksShop...');

    GmailApp.sendEmail(loopEmail, "DGS", text + text3 + text1 + text3, {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});


    }
}
```

As I said there is no need to use the File iterator. As it is only one file and you can get the id with a [List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22name%20%3D%20%27DrinksShopPartnerProgram.pdf%27%22%7D).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works excellently. Great support provided!